# "New" keyword when cloning object in JS

Tags: javascript

I kind of expected the following code to work - I wanted a clone that wasn't recursive.

It didn't...

Why, and what can I do to get around it?

```
person=new Object();
person.firstname="John";
person2 = new person; //Expected a new person object with firstname john    

"TypeError: object is not a function"
```

and the same for

```
person2 = new person()
```

Comment: `new` is used on a constructor function and clones its `prototype` object. May as well just write your own cloning function…

Comment: Bah, I over simplified my question.

Comment: If you need in depth explanations about Javascript object model, I suggest you to read [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/). Everything about objects, prototype, constructors and inheritance is explained.

Comment: I haven't read it in like 3 months, maybe I should re-read it... again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` operator in Javascript is applied to a **function** to create a new object with that functions **prototype chain** applied to the new object.  You can't apply it to an object directly.

If you want to clone an object in javascript its not a simple process.  You can see this answer for a list of possibilities: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript).  The simplest method is to use jQuery and $.extend.  But you can also write a common Javascript solution.  If you only want to use it for a specific type of object it may be fairly simple.

If you want to use new correctly you can create a constructor function like this

```
var Person = function() {
 this.firstname = "John";
};
var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();
```

That will create 2 new `Person` objects, independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = function() {
 this.firstname = 'John';
};

person2 = new Person();
```

The error thrown provides you with valuable information (a rarity in JavaScript, for sure) - you can only use the new operator when applying it to a function, not any other object.